# MySql Connector/Odbc 5.2(w) generates exception

Tags: asp.net, mysql, odbc

Hi I recently installed MySql Server 5.5 and MySql Connector/Odbc 5.2(w). Now, my old asp.net which worked perfectly in MySql Server 5.1 and Odbc Connector 3.51 generates an exception upon database operations.

The exception generated is **ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

I've changed the connection string to `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=localhost;Database=efloxdb;User=root;Password=admin;Option=3;`

The documentations haven't specified any further changes to be made. Can anyone find a solution to my problem? Any help would be appreciated